# ''.join() method omits the space between words

Tags: python

I'm building a simple morse code converter for a challenge. Basically I'm given a sentence and I have to convert that to its morse equivalent using a dictionary.  I'm using a basic for loop for this but once I try to convert my list into a string, I see that `''.join()` method completely omits the space between the morse translation.

This is my code:

```
def encode_morse(message):
    char_to_dots = {
  'A': '.-', 'B': '-...', 'C': '-.-.', 'D': '-..', 'E': '.', 'F': '..-.',
  'G': '--.', 'H': '....', 'I': '..', 'J': '.---', 'K': '-.-', 'L': '.-..',
  'M': '--', 'N': '-.', 'O': '---', 'P': '.--.', 'Q': '--.-', 'R': '.-.',
  'S': '...', 'T': '-', 'U': '..-', 'V': '...-', 'W': '.--', 'X': '-..-',
  'Y': '-.--', 'Z': '--..', ' ': ' ', '0': '-----',
  '1': '.----', '2': '..---', '3': '...--', '4': '....-', '5': '.....',
  '6': '-....', '7': '--...', '8': '---..', '9': '----.',
  '&': '.-...', "'": '.----.', '@': '.--.-.', ')': '-.--.-', '(': '-.--.',
  ':': '---...', ',': '--..--', '=': '-...-', '!': '-.-.--', '.': '.-.-.-',
  '-': '-....-', '+': '.-.-.', '"': '.-..-.', '?': '..--..', '/': '-..-.'
}
    print(message)
    message_list = list(message)
    morse_output = []

    for i in message_list:
        if i != ' ':
            morse_output.append(char_to_dots.get(str(i)))
        else:
            morse_output.append(' ')

    return ''.join(morse_output)
```

And this is the output:

```
EDABBIT CHALLENGE
FAILED: Test 1: '.-...--...-.....- -.-......-.-...-...-.--..' should equal '. -.. .- -... -... .. -   -.-. .... .- .-.. .-.. . -. --. .'
ERROR: Traceback:
   in <module>
  File "./frameworks/python/cw-2.py", line 28, in assert_equals
    expect(actual == expected, message, allow_raise)
  File "./frameworks/python/cw-2.py", line 18, in expect
    raise AssertException(message)
cw-2.AssertException: Test 1: '.-...--...-.....- -.-......-.-...-...-.--..' should equal '. -.. .- -... -... .. -   -.-. .... .- .-.. .-.. . -. --. .'
```

Comment: You successfully put a space between words, but you were supposed to put a space between the Morse representations of *individual characters*, and three spaces between words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't produce your output, as you claimed.

Replace the part

```
message_list = list(message)
morse_output = []

for i in message_list:
    if i != ' ':
        morse_output.append(char_to_dots.get(str(i)))
    else:
        morse_output.append(' ')

return ''.join(morse_output)
```

with

```
morse_output = []

for i in message:
    if i != ' ':
        morse_output.append(char_to_dots[i.upper()])
    else:
        morse_output.append('  ')

return ' '.join(morse_output)
```

*The explanation:*

1. No need for making a list from a string (`message_list = list(message)`), if you want to iterate over its chars.
2. You need to convert letters to the *capital* ones (`i.upper()`), because your dictionary contains only capital letter keys.
3. Using dictionary to assign value to a given key is as simple as add that key in square brackets after the dictionary name (`char_to_dots[i.upper()]`).
4. You need to separate *both* individual letters and individual words in the converted output — I chose 1 space for letter delimiter (`' '.join(morse_output)`) and another 2 for word delimiter (`morse_output.append('  ')`).

Answer (score 2):

You should specify that you want to join by a space (`' '`). Have you’re program say `' '.join(morse_output)`, not `''.join(morse_output)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert ' ':' ' into the dictionary to take care of the space (so you don't need the "if i != ' '" condition).

```
char_to_dots = {
'A': '.-', 'B': '-...', 'C': '-.-.', 'D': '-..', 'E': '.', 'F': '..-.',
'G': '--.', 'H': '....', 'I': '..', 'J': '.---', 'K': '-.-', 'L': '.-..',
'M': '--', 'N': '-.', 'O': '---', 'P': '.--.', 'Q': '--.-', 'R': '.-.',
'S': '...', 'T': '-', 'U': '..-', 'V': '...-', 'W': '.--', 'X': '-..-',
'Y': '-.--', 'Z': '--..', ' ': ' ', '0': '-----',
'1': '.----', '2': '..---', '3': '...--', '4': '....-', '5': '.....',
'6': '-....', '7': '--...', '8': '---..', '9': '----.',
'&': '.-...', "'": '.----.', '@': '.--.-.', ')': '-.--.-', '(': '-.--.',
':': '---...', ',': '--..--', '=': '-...-', '!': '-.-.--', '.': '.-.-.-',
'-': '-....-', '+': '.-.-.', '"': '.-..-.', '?': '..--..', '/': '-..-.',
' ': ' '
}

message ="HI THERE"
a = [char_to_dots[c] for c in message]
print(' '.join(a))
```

Output:

```
.... ..   - .... . .-. .
```